# TwoWayView StaggeredGridLayoutManager not working with StickyHeaders

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I am using [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) with StaggeredGridLayoutManager to create grid same with Pinterest app. 
Also I need to implement StickyHeaders in this view. For headers I'm using [eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders](https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders) like item decoration. The problem is: when half of the row has first header and half of the row has second header the header overlays above the part of row (see below)

x - items for first header
y - items for second header

xxx
xyy
yyy

So in this case header overlays the row "xyy".
But it must look something like this:

xxx
x
"hdr"
yyy
yy

(hdr - means header view).

So please help me, I'm trying to fix this very long time and trying to implement by different ways: using ListView with custom layout as item, using GridView and now this - ReclyclerView.